# Canvas mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my fiddle: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/rL0s2cmw/)

In the [original website](http://hostiran.net/) (Slide Section) when the mouse moves, the canvas is moving under the cursor.  However, in my fiddle, the cursor coordinates seem to be off. As in, a few inches above the cursor. Why is this happening?

Here's my `mousePosition` object:

```
var mousePosition = {
        x: 30 * canvas.width / 100,
        y: 30 * canvas.height / 100
    };
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must set to  `mousePosition.y = parameter.pageY;`